# What if a user has shared a potential virus?

Tags: support, virus

I came across an answer (which has upvotes also) while posting a question and searching for it, which may have shared **contain a potential virus program** on another website. *I may be wrong though*.

But anyways, what if anybody tries to share such a thing on this website?

Comment: What is a "potential virus program"? Is that a program that could transform into virus? Or do you mean "potentially contains a virus program" i.e. you are not 100% sure if the program is a virus or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you see a post with a link to software that contains a virus, you have a few options, basically boiling down to:

- If you believe the user did it unintentionally, point it out in a comment, and consider editing the post to replace the harmful link with a link to the clean version of the software (always use official sources for software downloads) if one exists, or perhaps editing the link out with explanation.
- If you believe the user did it intentionally, point it out in a comment and flag the post for moderator attention.
- If you believe it is *spam*, flag it as such.
- Rarer case: If you know the user did it unintentionally but, say, the official source was compromised somehow, leave a comment then consider notifying the maintainer of the official site.

If you *suspect* the program is harmful but aren't confident enough to edit / flag, you can raise the issue in comments first.

As for your specific case, assuming you are talking about SecurStick, for what it's worth I don't really see any negative user reports about it on the internet. There's a few users who mention false positive virus scans. The four symptoms in your bullet points seem like either user error, bugs, or interactions with your antivirus. That is not to say that it's OK, and you should never use tools you don't feel comfortable with (I probably wouldn't use SecurStick myself), but you may want to raise it in a comment and do some research before you start taking serious action.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Thank you for showing me the path, I will keep all the aspect in mind before posting in a question

Answer (score 6):

Have you confirmed it's a virus? If not, be careful about shouting from the rooftops because anti-virus applications can and do have false positives. Additionally your failure to understand the product or to get it to work properly are not indications that it is a virus.

You also shouldn't put large warnings like that in your question, it isn't necessary and it's pretty much unrelated to your actual question. As you haven't got enough rep to leave a comment on the specific answer flagging it for mod attention should be sufficient - if you are certain of your facts.

Comment: [That (inappropriate) post](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19740/pendrive-usb-drive-encryption-tool) on [SoftwareRecs.se] mentioned only **one** AV product ([Quick Heal Endpoint Security](http://www.seqrite.com/seqrite-endpoint-security-total)) flagging [SecurStick](http://www.withopf.com/tools/securstick/) as the potential virus. The OP did not check the product against a site like [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) and given the nature and reputation of SecurStick, and the lack of reputation of the AV product, I dare to conclude that it is a false positive.

Comment: @mustangDC None of that makes it a virus. A "network drive" can be there simply for convenience, or it might be a critical part of how it works (i.e. there may be a filter driver operating against that network drive).

Comment: I will recheck and get back to you ASAP

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Thank you for showing me the path, I will keep all the aspect in mind before posting in a question

Comment: I did not know about **VIrus Total** before, thanks for letting me know the super awesome website @slugster